# send a radio button value to the database

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

I have created form to apply values then insert to the table.
I need help to send a radio button value to the database

**nodejs**
**/ejs file**

```
 <label class="container" >5
    <input type="radio" name="_rate" id="_rate" value="5" required >
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
  </label>
  <label class="container">3
    <input type="radio" name="_rate" id="_rate" value="3">
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
  </label>
  <label class="container">1
    <input type="radio" name="_rate" id="_rate" value="1">
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
  </label>
```

**app.js**

```
var _rate= req.body._rate;
 
  var sql = `INSERT INTO [Test2] (rate) VALUES ('${_rate}')`;
```

the value always in table shows **null** !!

Answer (score 0):

What type of data is expected in your database field?
In any case, please use prepared statements to avoid type errors like :
`INSERT INTO [Test2] (rate) VALUES (?)`

Comment: the value is 5 or 3 or 1 as shows in html above.

Comment: i know the value but what is the type of this value ? why use single quotes to insert the value ?

Comment: the type is text,  and if I put double quotes error message appear: Invalid column name '1'.

Comment: Don't use double quotes, please use prepared statements instead : it's cleaner and it removes the risk of sql injection

Answer (score 0):

Ejs:

```
<form method="POST" action="/">
    <label class="container" >5
        <input type="radio" name="_rate" id="_rate" value="5" required >
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
   </label>
   <label class="container">3
       <input type="radio" name="_rate" id="_rate" value="3">
       <span class="checkmark"></span>
   </label>
   <label class="container">1
       <input type="radio" name="_rate" id="_rate" value="1">
       <span class="checkmark"></span>
   </label>
</form>
```

Nodejs:

```
const express = require('express');
const mysql = require('mysql2');
const app = express();

const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: //'localhost' or you hostname,
    user: //'root' or your username,
    password: //yourpassword,
    database: //'database name',
})

app.post("/", async (req, res)=>{
    const _rate = req.body._rate
    await db.query("INSERT INTO Test2 (rate) VALUES (`${_rate}`)", (err, result) {
    if (err) {
       //Handle error
    } else {
       //Do whatever you want with `result`
    }
})

app.listen(3000, ()=>{
   console.log('Server started working on port 3000')
})
```